# HTML Internet Explorer 6 overflow bug

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6

I have the following problem and I don't know how to solve it. I have an HTML table and one of the cells contains an input element. My problem is that in Firefox when I type something that overflows the input width the text will be hidden (which is the behaviour I want), but in Internet Explorer 6 the width of the input will be automatically expanded and the whole page format goes to hell because of it.
I've been doing some googling and it all points out to the so called "overflow bug" in IE 6, yet I have absolutely no idea how to solve it.

I've tried setting overflow: hidden on both the input element and the containing cell (td) with no effect. I've also tried setting a max-width again with no success.

Any ideas?

**IMPORTANT** Due to the way the application I'm working on is programmed I can only modify the CSS of the element, not other HTML properties...

Comment: What code you have written? Can I see?

Comment: @Ahsan Rathod I wish I could show you but the HTML is generated through a very complex series of Java method calls. I could show you an CSS extract

Comment: Try to edit like I did in my Answer

Answer (score 0):

can you set max input characters on the box that may help solve it!

hold on try this css!

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that due to the way the application I'm working is working, I can only modify the CSS not the HTML properties of an element...

Comment: that is css! you might need to make the selector more specific but should work!

Comment: thanks :) I only noticed the first part of your answer. Let me try it, I'll get back to you

Comment: @Treemonkey Sorry but it doesn't. Setting table-layout to fixed shrinks all the cells to a minimum cell size... Even worse :)

Comment: @Victor :( dang! dont have IE6 anymore either to help further, could try getting a developer addon and test changing css properties, could try the old zoom:1; on the particular cell but i doubt that will do much

Comment: @ victor try word-break:break-all; on the input aswell!

Answer (score 0):

The first question would be : Do you really need to support IE6 ? Even microsoft stopped supporting it that a sign isn't it ??

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

You could try to put a DIV inside your TD. Set a fixed width in the style of the div and set its overflow to hidden. Then put your input box inside the div.
This way even if the input box expands it should be hidden by the Div hidden overflow. It might not be pretty since the box will look cut at the end but it won't destroy your design.

I'm not sure it will work though since it's a bug it might not conform to the rest of the css either.

Comment: Unfortunately yes I need to. Apparently the customers of the application I'm developing haven't learned of new browser versions... Also, I can't really add another DIV inside the TD. This would imply me changing some Java class that generates HTML that is used in all sorts of other places and who knows what could happen. The only safe thing I can do is change the CSS of existing elements. Oh I love corporate development :)

Comment: I must say that I never met this behavior even when I was coding websites for IE6. To be sure I understand : You have a textbox input in a cell and when you type something in the textbox its size changes according to the text you type ? We are talking about a <input type="text"> element ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. The input grows larger to accomodate the text being written. Setting a fixed or max width in CSS doesn't work.

Comment: I take it you can't swap the input to a textarea of 1 line ? Textareas  might not be subject to the overflow bug

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
input [type=text] {
    width: 100px; \\ That suits you best
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Nope... I tried already and also setting overflow on the containing td and it doesn't work.

Comment: Try this css attribute: `white-space:nowrap;` then tell me that it works or not?